# How to merge collections based on object's particular key's value match in laravel6?

Tags: laravel-6, laravel-collection, laravel-6.2

I have three collections.

SalaryCollection

[image]

BonusCollection

[image]

Deduction Collection

[image]

All of them have date which is common in some of them.
I want to merge these three into one collection in a way that object with same date in three becomes one as a result.
Something like this:

```
#items:array:2[
0=>{
+"date":"1-2020"
+"salaries":36500.0
+"deductions":1500.0
+"bonuses":7000.0
}
1=>{
+"date":"2-2020"
+"salaries":20000.0
+"deductions":1000.0
+"bonuses":5000.0
}
]
```

How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is the best way to do it but this is how i made it worked.

```
     $salaryCollection = $salaryCollection->map(function ($item, $key) use ($bonusCollection) {
        $single_bonus = $bonusCollection->where('date', $item->date);
        if (!$single_bonus->isEmpty()) {
            return collect($item)->put('bonuses', $single_bonus->first()->bonuses);
        } else {
            return collect($item)->put('bonuses', 0);
        }
    });

    $salaryCollection = $salaryCollection->map(function ($item, $key) use ($deductionCollection) {
        $single_deduction = $deductionCollection->where('date', $item['date']);
        if (!$single_deduction->isEmpty()) {
            return collect($item)->put('deductions', $single_deduction->first()->deductions);
        } else {
            return collect($item)->put('deductions', 0);
        }
    });
```